# How to create a react sidebar navigation with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, themes, admin

How we can create a react sidebar admin themes with react router?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's not a specific programming problem and should be closed! take a look at [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render components with different layouts/elements using react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999324/how-do-i-render-components-with-different-layouts-elements-using-react-router-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a sidebar examples .

1. React Router Sidebar 1
   [React Router sidebar example1](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)
2. React Router Sidebar 2
   [React Router sidebar example2](https://codesandbox.io/s/d9rpd7046)

    
    
   You can use react router sidebar from both the links.

Comment: If you have any issues with both the example you can ask here

Answer (score 2):

Maybe see a Sidebar example of
[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper component that is the sidebar itself. Then, setup your desired routes to be wrapped with a sidebar.

This approach has the benefit of keeping all the logic in your router without requiring modifications to any of your current components. It will also work great for server side rendered apps if you decide to move in that direction.