# add a navbar inside privateRoutes in react-router 6

Tags: javascript, react-router, navbar

I have only seen examples of creating a `<Navbar />` in `react-router` placing it outside `<Routes>`

example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

How can I render `<Navbar/>` inside the `PrivateRoutes` as I can't place it outside `<Routes>`

```
return (
  <Router>
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
    
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: The `Navbar` component can't go between `AuthContext.Provider` and `Routes`? It's unclear what any issue is or what you are expecting an answer to be. Or are you specifically wanting to render the `Navbar` on ***only*** the protected routes? If so, do this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999387/8690857

Comment: yep! sorry for not being clear, only render navbar on the protected routes

Comment: Ah, then yeah, creating a layout route component that renders the `Navbar` and an `Outlet` for the nested routes is the way to go. That `Route` with neither `path` nor `element` is the a good place for it.